# How to separate alloys?

Tags: melting-point, alloy

How do you separate metal alloys into their constituent elements, especially industrially? I don't think you can always use melting points, because alloys, depending on the composition (looking at phase curves) can have one common melting point.

Here's a phase diagram for a copper-nickel alloy, which I think is a system where both components are completely soluble in one another in all ratios.

[image]

This composition cannot be separated by cooling it down, as I understand it (even though, as mentioned [here](https://books.google.de/books?id=7YZVAwAAQBAJ&pg=PT191&lpg=PT191&dq=cu-ni%20alloy%20completely&source=bl&ots=NAR0JPlrCo&sig=X8uDc9fCBy67dfpMac2Ud8YpytM&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj2sdf5v67QAhVDOBQKHSfmC20Q6AEIVDAI#v=onepage&q=cu-ni%20alloy%20completely&f=false), the composition would not be uniform if the molten alloy is not cooled down slowly enough). As described [here](http://sv.rkriz.net/classes/MSE2094_NoteBook/96ClassProj/examples/cu-ni.html), the solid that would start to separate (the alpha phase) is itself an alloy.

EDIT: What about electrolysis? Could that work here?

Comment: Separate one alloy from another, i.e. distinguish them apart, or separate out the various elements?

Comment: @JonCuster separate them into the consituting elements

Comment: Maybe it can be interesting I don't know. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zone_melting

Comment: @Hexacoordinate-C I think this is rather used for purifying, don't know if this can really be used to take like 50 tons of steel alloy and separate out the 11% chromium some alloys seem to contain.

Comment: When you have a mix of different component you can use the eutectic point(s). If you have only two elements the one which is the more will melt (or the other i don't remember) after the other then you can separate the liquid and the solid and do it again and again as you want. If you have more, you'll need to do it again in other parts.

Comment: @Hexacoordinate-C I think this doesn't work for every alloy. I've added the example of Ni-Cu in the question.

Comment: I think this depends heavily on the metal. For example, purifying iron for steel via the [Bessemer process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessemer_process). Gold can be purified in part by cyanide leaching, but there are other methods of [parting gold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gold_parting).

Comment: What do you mean by electrolysis?

Comment: @IvanNeretin I'm really not sure where I'm going with this, but say we stick two electrodes that are up to the task into the molten alloy and pump current through it. I assume that even though the resistance will be a lot higher for most metals due to higher temp, it will still basically work as a conductor, so it'll just get warm. But what if we were to dump some salt into it? http://web.ornl.gov/info/reports/1963/3445603652660.pdf mentions that that can lead to loss of conductivity, so electrolysis could happen (maybe ionization of metal at anode?). Or would that still only affect the salt?

Comment: Essentially, the phases formed from molten metals and molten salts (given that they mix at all, which is not always so) may be either "metal-like" or "salt-like". In the first case it would conduct electric current using electrons, much like electric wires in your house, and would be able to do so for years without any change. In the second case it would be able to undergo electrolysis, like any molten salt, and you might be able to tune the conditions so that the metals separate. Then it is just another recipe starting with _"Dissolve both metals..."_ (dissolve in a molten salt, that is).

Comment: there's a series of videos about a chemistry buff who distills platinum from catalytic converter dust from the roadside, and does other fun experiments of that kind.

Comment: @IvanNeretin yeah, you make a good point. Thanks)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You seem to approach the separation of alloys much like the separation of water-soluble salts, probably based on the fact that both involve the liquid/solid phase diagrams, which may even look alike. This is wrong; these systems are *fundamentally* different.

Say, you have a water solution of some well-soluble salt which you need to recrystallize. You cool it down, so the salt precipitates. You filter the crystals out of the solution, then you probably rinse them with something which would remove the traces of solution without damaging the crystals, or just let them dry.

Now suppose you have a metal alloy, maybe not even of the kind you mentioned above; let it have a simple eutectic diagram, like Bi-Cd.
[image: Bi-Cd phase diagram]

You melt it, then carefully cool it down to a certain point, and end up with a mixture of some (supposedly) pure metal crystals with a still-liquid alloy. **What good does it do?** You can't really filter it. You can't rinse the crystals. You can't let them "dry". It is **useless**.

With metal alloys, your best bet is to dissolve **both** metals and separate them chemically, based on their different properties. In some relatively rare cases, you might be able to melt the alloy and perform chemical conversion of one component without affecting the other; examples include [cupellation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cupellation) or Bessemer process referenced earlier in the comments. In yet more exotic cases, you might be lucky enough to chemically etch one component out of *solid* alloy; this is how [Raney nickel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raney_nickel) is made. Unless you are that lucky, go back to the start of this paragraph.

Comment: Thanks for the information on cupellation and Raney nickel, that is helpful. So, you're saying that it generally very much depends on the case? Also, could you elaborate in your answer on how metal composition phase diagrams are different from non-metal ones? As in the sources I linked to, the behaviour of the alloy when heated is shown. The recrystallizing you bring up is valid, but it doesn't have much to do with the issue. Also, where's the problem in decanting molten metal and let it drain unter its weight, separating the residue, using something like a modified Bessemer container?

Comment: Generally you have to dissolve both metals and do some wet chemistry. As for the phase diagrams, they are not very different, but the systems are. Molten metal is not quite like water. You decant it, and a good deal of it just remains there (thanks to higher viscosity and surface tension), and you can't rinse it off, nor would it evaporate like water (since its vapor pressure is way lower than that of water).