# Iron-platinum refining

Tags: metal, transition-metals, metallurgy, alloy

If I have an iron-platinum alloy, can I put this into a solution of $\ce{HCl}$ to dissolve the iron, leaving a $\ce{Pt}$ precipitate?

I know that Fe dissolves in $\ce{HCl}$ to form $\ce{FeCl2}$ and $\ce{H2}$, and I know that $\ce{Pt}$ does not dissolve in $\ce{HCl}$.

But will the $\ce{Fe-Pt}$ bonding affect the Fe dissolution?

Comment: Related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/62787/how-to-separate-alloys/62812#62812

Comment: Given the broad solubility ranges and ordered low temperature phases, the general answer is no - those are alloys, not phase separated.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the concentration of Pt in your alloy.

If the concentration of Pt is to high the HCl will not or not sufficently attack the alloy.

In this case you could try to melt your alloy with some additional Fe, to lower the Pt concentration and then hit it with HCl again.

You could also try to boil it in HCl to increase the reactivity of the acid (do it in a fumehood or outdoors).